# Is "And every time the ladies pass they be like 'Hi Will'" correct grammar?

Tags: slang, grammaticality-in-context

In the [lyrics of the song *Miami*](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tlav3btjtyj72ujfhys2mswo2hu?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) by Will Smith it says:

> And every time the ladies pass they be like "Hi Will"

Is this correct grammar? I wonder because I thought that one should either change "be" to "are" or add "will" after "they" (so that it's "they'll be like ...").

Comment: It's a lyric so correct grammar is ignored in favour of scansion and idiomatic usage, in other words, anything goes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_be

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to say

> And every time the ladies pass they *would be* like "Hi Will"

meaning the ladies are showing their attraction to Will.

in the same way

> That car over there? That *would be* a Ferrari.

*would be* is used to describe what or how something is.